# xp to level formula

Tags: functions

So I have this function to calculate how much xp is needed to get to a level.
`25 * level * (1+level)`

but im having trouble making a xp to level function. I have tried a few things that people on Discord gave me.

`(25 * xp) + ((25 * xp)^2)`

`((xp / 25) / (1-xp))`

just to name a few. but none work.

this is made with code, but i thought id ask here since its more math related than code related.

Comment: I’m trying to clarify your question. Please let me know if I am correct: Suppose you are at level $L$ with 0 leftover xp, then to get to level $L+1$, you need $25L(1+L)$ xp?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes that is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the amount of xp needed to get to the next level be $x$ and the current level to be $y$. We have that $$x=25\cdot y(1+y)$$Expand and divide by $25$: $$y^2+y=\frac x{25}$$Complete the square $$\begin{align}y^2+y+\frac14&=\frac x{25}+\frac14\\\left(y+\frac12\right)^2&=\frac{4x+25}{100}\\y&=\frac{\sqrt{4x+25}}{10}-\frac12\end{align}$$(We have to take the positive square root because the level is positive)

---

Test: Let's say that level(or $y$)$=25$. Then xp needed(or $x$)=$25 \cdot 25 \cdot (25+1)=16250$.

Now we can test the formula:$$\begin{align}&\frac{\sqrt{4\cdot16250+25}}{10}-\frac12\\&=\frac{\sqrt{65000+25}}{10}-\frac12\\&=\frac{255}{10}-\frac12\\&=25.5-0.5\\&=25\end{align}$$ which is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. Please put dollar signs around your maths and put slash in front of square root. Look up “Mathjax tutorial”

Comment: ok will do that

Comment: The other slash, lol.

Comment: backslash like this: \?